# $(1-h)^n \geq 1-nh$ for any $h \geq 0$ and $n \geq 1$

Tags: inequality

I am not exactly sure where the above comes from.

All I can do is:

$$(1-h)^n = \sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i}(-h)^i = 1-nh + {n \choose 2}h^2 - {n \choose 3}h^3 ... + (-1)^nh^n$$

How do I know that ${n \choose 2}h^2 - {n \choose 3}h^3 ... + (-1)^nh^n$ is not less than zero.

Comment: Use induction on n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction,it is clear for $$n=2\\ (1-h)^{ 2 }\geq 1-2h$$ let say it is true for n
$$(1-h)^{ n }\geq 1-nh$$
we must show that $$ (1-h)^{ n+1 }\geq 1-\left( n+1 \right) h$$

so
$$(1-h)^{ n+1 }=(1-h)^{ n }\left( 1-h \right) \ge \left( 1-nh \right) \left( 1-h \right) =$$ $$=1-h-nh+n{ h }^{ 2 }\ge 1-h-nh=1-\left( n+1 \right) h$$